# Select the containing tr of an active a tag with only css

Tags: html, css

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="some-link" class="active">some text</a>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="some-link">some text</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I can only use css selector properties to select the tr and add some properties to it if my anchor tag is active without any JS or JQuery.
Please help!

Comment: In short, You can't. There is no way to select parent element with css. May be in future it is possible but not now. There is a proposed [**:has()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) selector but it is not supported by any browser yet.

Comment: If the table row consists of only one cell, why not make the <a> fill the entire cell (`display:block, width:100%; height:100%` etc) and then it will look like the whole cell is highlighted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone already suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector), the best way would be to simply add an "active" class to your tr

```
<tr class="active">
```